# Is it bad etiquette to leave comments about my answer on newly answered questions ?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

Let's say I post a new answer to an old question, and that my answer is objectively better (imagine for the sake of the question) than any of the other answers. Is it considered bad etiquette to notify people by way of comments of the superiority of the new answer, or is it better just to let nature work its course?

Comment: I would say post the answer and leave it alone, no need to bump with a comment.  Those searching for the (now old) question will find the new answer and find it useful themselves (or not).

Comment: What are you expecting them to do in response to your comment?  Are you expecting them to realize a mistake in their answer (and ideally fix it), to just think your answer is cool but not actually do anything, be annoyed and do nothing, or what?

Comment: @Servy at the very least fix the mistake or acknowledge the inadequacy, but ideally also acknowledge the better answer

Comment: @aaronman So you're assuming the other answer has mistakes and that you're pointing them out.  That's not something you stated in your question.  Even if they did think your answer was better, that doesn't mean theirs is wrong.  Now if you assume the other answer has a mistake and you point that mistake out, that changes the question quite dramatically.

Comment: @Servy well in the main case I'm thinking about the mistake found is somewhat nitpicky so I didn't mention it

Comment: @aaronman If it's a nitpicky mistake that's not particularly germane to the problem at hand then you do need to ask yourself if it's worth bothering with.  It's most likely not worth downvoting over if you feel it's a nitpicky issue, but if you do want to comment anyway so that the poster can make there answer at least a bit better, then that's fine, just don't get too worked up if they choose to not bother fixing a nitpicky issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New answers to old questions are generally *not* better.  What they usually are is someone promoting their blog, making a comment, or advertising.  Answers that genuinely add something substantial to an old post are comparatively rare.

The usual responses apply.  Downvote, flag as spam, etc.

Comment: This new answer is clearly superior to the others.

Comment: Is this a sarcastic comment? Also when did I say anything about spam

Comment: The comment is meant to be illustrative, in a humorous way.  Surprised that I have to explain that.  Also surprised that you appear to be taking a combative tone; if you bring up new answers to old questions, then you also bring up all of the common problems that such answers bring, and spam is one of those problems.

Comment: In addition, the clarifying comments below your question suggest that a better response would be to point out the original answer's shortcomings in a comment below the old answer, not in a new answer (unless it really is a new answer that adds substantial value to the question).  People leaving comments as answers on old questions are part of the problem, not part of the solution.

Comment: I hope my answer wasn't spam, if I seemed to have a combative tone it was because for the sake of the question I asked you to suspend disbelief and imagine the answer was indeed better, If you need to see to believe I could show the question in question but would prefer not to

Comment: A specific example is always preferable to wandering generalities.

Comment: It's just that then I feel like I'm promoting my answer in an even worse way than before by showing it to everyone here and basically saying look how great I am

Comment: Oh, don't worry about that.  It will probably be downvoted into oblivion. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924446/finding-a-missing-number-from-two-lists/17182884#17182884

Comment: Your probably right hopefully not because of the answer but because of my rudeness :)

Comment: A perfectly good answer.  While it probably won't get 10 votes, it should get a few.  That's the price you pay for arriving late to the party. :)  Sometimes I'll drop an answer like this into one of the public chat rooms for review by the participants there.

Comment: What do you mean by dropping an answer in for review?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/10487257#10487257 ... Use sparingly. :)

Answer (score 13):

If you notice a *problem* with some other answer, and you've posted an answer to fix it, then commenting on the other answer would be fine.  A comment saying, "Your answer doesn't handle the case where the [...], but this answer [link] addresses that problem."  is appropriate.

Just writing something like, "I've added an answer here, and it's better." isn't really an appropriate comment.

Comment: I figured as much, what if you post a comment about the error and it is ignored by the answerer

Comment: @aaronman The site is more about helping the masses than about helping a particular person. If the answerer ignores your post, no big deal. Others will see it and benefit.

Comment: @aaronman Then you can downvote if you feel that is appropriate, as with any answer that has a problem, if you feel the problem is "bad enough" to make the answer not helpful or even harmful.

Comment: @Servy your answer was originally better I only chose to accept the other because of his helpful comments